# "expression must have pointer to object type" error despite of not using pointers at all in the program

Tags: c, pointers

"expression must have pointer to object type" error despite of not using pointers at all in the program.
error occurs in line

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int j = 0, key, i=0;

    char l = 'r', al = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};

    while (l != al[j])
        j++;

    key = j - i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you beleive `a1[j]` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the declaration

```
char l='r',
     al = { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
```

you're declaring `al` to be a single `char` value, but you're attempting to initialize it with a string literal, which is an array of `char`.

`al` needs to be declared as either an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`.  To declare it as an array, do the following:

```
char l='r',
     al[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // braces not required here,
                                          // array size is computed from 
                                          // length of string literal
```

To declare it as a pointer, use

```
char l='r';
const char *al = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

When you declare `al` as an array, the compiler will set aside enough storage to store a copy of the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, and the contents of this array will be modifiable (although the length will be fixed - you will not be able to add new elements or remove existing elements from the array).

When you declare `al` as a pointer, the compiler will simply copy the address of the first character in the string literal to the pointer<sup>1</sup>.  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to undefined behavior; it *may* cause your code to crash, or it may not.  As a rule, if you declare something to point to a string literal, you want to declare it `const`:

```
const char *al = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

This way if you accidentally write something like

```
al[0] = 'z';
```

the compiler will catch it and issue a diagnostic.

The `[]` subscript operator works for both array and pointer expressions, so your `l != al[j]` test will work the same way for both.

---

<sup>1.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array".</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not using pointers is the problem. You get this because `al` must either be a pointer type or an array type, and not a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialise a `char` with a string literal, which can only initialise pointers to `char` or arrays of `char`.

To fix this error, either change your code to

```
  char l='r',
  *al = { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
```

or to

```
  char l='r',
  al[] = { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
```

The upper statement makes `al` a pointer, while the lower one makes `al` an array.